# How to phpUnit-cover continue, break,

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

Simple question, how do i cover lines with continue, break, ... with phpUnit and xDebug?
System is set up and running, code coverage is generated, all well, but some lines with continue, break and so on are marked as "not covered", so method is marked "not covered", so class is ... you know what.

Example:

```
if ($taskData['srcType']=='c') {
    continue;
}
```

The Line 'continue;' is marked "not covered.

System: Win7, xDebug 2.2.3, phpUnit 3.7.27

Comment: I believe this to be a nasty bug in either PHPUnit or XDebug. This issue probably covers some part of this: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/70

Comment: Found the issue: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/129

Answer (score 1):

Well, a nasty solution could be to exclude those lines from the code coverage statistics.

Add `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart` and `@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` around that line.

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks